# Injective function from $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is surjective

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

If a function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is injective, is it automatically surjective?

Comment: This is true if $f$ is linear, but not for general functions.

Comment: Can you think of a simpler situation e.g. $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ - what is the answer there? What answer do you expect? Or reflect that one definition of an infinite set is that there is a bijection with a proper subset.

Comment: $f(x,y) = (x,0)$

Comment: Thanks. Bit of a silly question...I was trying to answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1035836/f-mathbbr2-to-mathbbr2-is-differentiable-and-satisfies-an-inequality (which I found later). I got injective and was wondering if there's some way to get surjective for free. Anyway, this solution is much nicer than what I was trying.

Comment: What is true is that, if $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is an injective entire function, then $f$ is a nonconstant linear function (whence $f$ is a surjection).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What do you think about $$f(x,y)=(e^x,e^y) \ \ ?$$

Answer (score 4):

If $X$ were a finite set, then injectivity *would* imply surjectivity and vice-versa.  However, the mere existence of an injective-but-not-surjective or surjective-but-not-injective function $f:X \rightarrow X$ is equivalent to $X$ being infinite.

This is a consequence of the fact$^\dagger$ that a set $X$ is infinite $\iff$ there is a subset $A \subsetneq X$ of the same cardinality as $X$; that is, we can find a bijection $g: A \rightarrow X$.  To get a surjective-but-not-injective function $X \rightarrow X$, take any [extension](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1129607/what-does-it-mean-to-extend-a-function) of $g$ to all of $X$.  Next, $g^{-1}$ gives an example of an injective-but-not-surjective function $X \rightarrow X$.

---

In the analysis setting, let's first think of functions $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that satisfy this condition, and from there the idea can be generalized to higher dimensions.  For intuition's sake, let's see if we can restrict ourselves to differentiable functions.  Note that a differentiable, injective function $f$ is necessarily *continuous* and strictly monotone increasing (or decreasing).  The only way for $f$ to not be surjective would be for the derivative to limit to zero as $x \rightarrow \infty$ or $x \rightarrow -\infty$.  In other words, the function achieves a horizontal asymptote.  Examples include $f(x) = e^x$ and $f(x) = \arctan(x)$.  We can see that the former is injective as $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x$, but not surjective since $f(x) > 0$ for all $x$.

---

$\dagger$ See **[here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Infinite_Set_Equivalent_to_Proper_Subset)** for further discussion.